# I need to create list in python from OpenOffice Calc columns

Tags: python-2.7, scripting, openoffice-calc

The problem is I have large amounts of data in OpenOffice Calc, approximately 3600 entries for each of 4 different categories and 3 different sets of this data, and I need to run some calculations on it in python. I want to create lists corresponding each of the four categories. I am hoping someone can help guide me to an easy-ish, efficient way to do this whether it be script or importing data.  I am using python 2.7 on a windows 8 machine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

My current method i am trying is to save odf file as cvs then use genfromtxt(from numpy).

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('C:\Users\tomdi_000\Desktop\Load modeling(WSU)\PMU Data\Data18-1fault-Alvey-csv trial.csv', delimiter=',')
print(my_data)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1352, in genfromtxt
    fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU'))
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 147, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 496, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: C:\Users   omdi_000\Desktop\Load modeling(WSU)\PMU Data\Data18-1fault-Alvey-csv trial.csv not found.
```

the error stems from this code in _datasource.py

```
    # NOTE: _findfile will fail on a new file opened for writing.
    found = self._findfile(path)
    if found:
        _fname, ext = self._splitzipext(found)
        if ext == 'bz2':
            mode.replace("+", "")
        return _file_openers[ext](found, mode=mode)
    else:
        raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
```

Comment: Yes, it needs a full path or a relative path relative to the folder where you run the script.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your path string `'C:\Users\tomdi_000\Desktop\Load modeling(WSU)\PMU Data\Data18-1fault-Alvey-csv trial.csv'` contains an escape sequence - `\t`. Since you are not using [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/1426065), the `\t` is being interpreted as a tab character, similar to the way a `\n` is interpreted as a newline. If you look at the line starting with `IOError:`, you'll see a tab has been inserted in its place. You don't get this problem with UNIX-style paths, as they use forward slashes `/`.

There are two ways around this. The first is to use a raw string literal:

```
r'C:\Users\tomdi_000\Desktop\Load modeling(WSU)\PMU Data\Data18-1fault-Alvey-csv trial.csv'
```

(note the `r` at the beginning). As explained in the link above, raw string literals don't interpret back slashes `\` as beginning an escape sequence.

The second way is to use a UNIX-style path with forward slashes as path delimiters:

```
'C:/Users/tomdi_000/Desktop/Load modeling(WSU)/PMU Data/Data18-1fault-Alvey-csv trial.csv'
```

This is fine if you're hard-coding the paths into your code, or reading from a file that you generate, but if the paths are getting generated automatically, such as reading the results of an `os.listdir()` command for example, it's best to use raw strings instead.

---

If you're going to be using `numpy` to do the calculations on your data, then using `np.genfromtxt()` is fine. However, for working with CSV files, you'd be much better off using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. It includes all sorts of functions for reading columns and rows, and doing data transformation. If you're just reading the data then storing it in a list, for example, `csv` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thanks you were right on with the escape sequence so i did a made a few subtle adjustments to code and but i am still stuck. I moved the file in hopes that shorter path helped and added the extra black slash to take care of escape sequence issue.  `from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('C:\\volts.cvs', delimiter=',')
print(my_data)`   File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 496, in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
IOError: C:\volts.cvs not found.

Comment: I think im going to look into csv module and see if i can get it to work with that.